# Append result of CloudKit into array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, cloudkit

i declare the contact variable as an empty string array

```
  var contact = [String] ()
```

then I made a query to output the results from CloudKit, when I accessed the controller once, var contact succeeded in adding an array

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Note", predicate: predicate)
    database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (record, error) in
        for record: CKRecord in record! {
            let name = record.value(forKeyPath: "content") as! String
            print ("There is a note \"\(name)\"")
            self.contact.append(name)
            }
        }
  

   self.contact.append (name)

  print ("There is a note \" \ (name) \ "")
```

but when accessing for the second time, the var contact becomes empty again

```
  print ("check all array append \ (contact)")
```

[Succes append firstime access the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHD0j.png)

[Failed append secondtime access the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auVZp.png)

i use variable contact in other function

func sendSOS() {

```
if canSendText() {

    
   
    //compese message with google link
    let googleLink = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + String(myLatitude!) + "+" + String(myLongtitude!)
    let SMStext = "EMERGENCY!!, Tolong Bantu saya di lokasi Latitude: " + String(myLatitude!) + "\n Longtitude: " + String(myLongtitude!) + "  " + googleLink
    let messsageCompose = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messsageCompose.messageComposeDelegate = self
    messsageCompose.recipients = contact;
    messsageCompose.body = SMStext
    present(messsageCompose, animated: true, completion: nil)

}else{
    // create the alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No SMS available.", message: "Please find a better location and try again!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    // add an action (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return
}
```

}

Comment: More context is missing : when is contact initialized ? Is it in instance of some kind ? ...

Comment: i initialized contact in. contactcontroller.swift, and using in in other function

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine what's going on because you're leaving out how the `contact` array is initialized relative to your `CKQuery`.

The `database.perform` line looks a little suspicious. I'm pretty sure that returns an array of `CKRecords` so you should have:

```
database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
  //records is an optional array
  if let records = records{
    for record in records{
      //You might have to parse record.values to get its key/value pairs
      let name = record["content"] as? String ?? "No Name"
      print("There is a note: \(name)")
      //:::
      self.contact.append(name)
    }
  }
}
```

As a side note, I recommend using `CKQueryOperation` for all queries ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckqueryoperation)). It's a cleaner way to manage data flowing from CloudKit.